# Can a stereo microscope be used for mycology?

Tags: microbiology, microscopy

I have a need for a stereo microscope to do electronics work. I also have a strong desire for a stereo microscope to do mycology. I would like to be able to,

- Clearly identify mycelium, from bacterial contamination (no interest in bacteria).
- Be able to isolate spores of mycelium.
- Identify dikaryon, from monokaryon
- Ideally, but not required be able to identify different types of mycelium that are undesirable (mold).

Could I take a trinocular stereo microscope and add a barrow lens that increases the zoom and decreases the focal length, and use it for biology as desired above? Some stereomicroscopes that have 2x Barlow advertise 225x, like the AmScope ZM2225NT.

What would the downsides of this approach be?